# give unique id based on other columns

Tags: r

I have data like this

```
a1  a2   a3
1   22   44
1   22   33
2   44    3
2   55   5
3   22   7
```

I like to give unique ids based on the a1 and a2 combination:

```
a1  a2   a3   id
1   22   44    1
1   22   33    1
2   44    3    2
2   55   5     3
3   22   7     4
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way in base R is to probably use `factor`:

```
> as.integer(factor(with(mydf, paste(a1, a2))))
[1] 1 1 2 3 4
```